# How to attach screenshots at Pytest JUNIT xml to appear on Azure DevOps?

Tags: selenium, junit, azure-devops, pytest, azure-pipelines

How can I add screenshots automatically at the JUNIT xml with Pytest? I want the screenshots taken during the execution of tests to be attached to the report, but the Pytest documentation of this part is not very clear.

Also, [Azure DevOps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml#arguments) says it can automatically upload all generated files as attachments. Does this replaces the need to attach manually the files ? How does it attach the file A with the test X?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the screenshots taken during the execution of tests to be
> attached to the report

You can try to call the [Create Test Result Attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create%20test%20result%20attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api to attach screenshots to the test Attachment tab.

Sample script in powershell task:

```
$file= [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("filepath\$Name.png")
$Base64file= [Convert]::ToBase64String($file)
echo $Base64file

$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/test/Runs/$(runId)/results/$($TestResultID)/attachments?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = "
    {
       `"stream`": `"$Base64file`",
       `"fileName`": `"$Name.png`",
       `"comment`": `"Test attachment upload`",
       `"attachmentType`": `"GeneralAttachment`"
    }"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

This [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65992004/azure-devops-screenshot-are-not-showing-in-attachment-tab) gives detailed guidelines, you can refer to it for details.

In addition, you could directly try to use the `Publish screenshots for test failure` task from the extension [Publish test result screenshot](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Genetec.publish-test-result-screenshot).

This extension provides a Build task to integrate in your continuous integration pipeline. This task will upload screenshots to test result reports from sources other than Visual Studio Test (TRX), for instance, from jUnit.